# Stop opening VLC in python

Tags: python, command

I wrote a little code which scans the wifi signals in the air and according to the amount plays one or another audio file.

```
import time
import subprocess
import os

while True:
    output = subprocess.Popen("airport en1 -s", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
    lines = output.split('\n')
    n = len(lines)
    if n < 10:
        print os.path.exists('/Users/shirin/Desktop/wifi/1.mp3') 
        p = subprocess.Popen(['/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC','/Users/shirin/Desktop/wifi/1.mp3'])
    elif n > 10:
        print os.path.exists('/Users/shirin/Desktop/wifi/1.mp3') 
        p = subprocess.Popen(['/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC','/Users/shirin/Desktop/wifi/1.mp3'])
```

Now my problem is that, when I run the file through the terminal it keeps running the code over and over again and I do not know how to stop it. It also does not stop when I close the terminal. 
So my question:
How can I tell python to run the code once and then stop?

already super thanks!

Comment: why that `while True:` ?

Comment: Don't use a while loop  if you only want to run it once

Comment: Where in this code sits the loop then? I copy pasted this code together which is never smart, I know, but I am a newby

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You have a `while True:` and no condition to break the loop, insert a `break` after reproducing the audio file so the loop could stop.
- Even if you close the program VLC would be running until you manually stop it. This is because you are just calling an external command. If you want to reproduce the audio from python you can use another library like [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can call `p.terminate()` if you want to terminate your application.

You can also call `p.kill()` if your application is not responsive.

Now, let's say you want to stop the application and stop VLC.

Have `except KeyboardInterrupt:` in your code and call `p.terminate()` when you stop the script.

```
while True:
    try:
    ... #code goes here.
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        p.terminate()
```

Comment: I want to add a "terminate"-code line within the script. Do you know anything about that?